# Copy just the last line of serial output from rs232 weight scale to clipboard

Tags: command-line, tty, serial-port, clipboard

I bought an rs232 weight scale for a point of sale and I'm having trouble to get useful data on the PC.

If I do `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` I can get the weight in plain number(`0.500` for example), which is what I need, but it prints the value constantly(like every 200ms or so), so if I try to output that to a file the result is:

```
   0.500
^C^B   0.500
^C^B   0.500
^C^B   0.500
// and it goes on...
```

I need a way to stop `cat` after the first time it outputs a value so I won't end with a file that will end up growing until there's no room left.

Additionaly I have to copy that value to the clipboard, or something like that to paste it into the POS Software later.

I tried using `xcopy` like this `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | xcopy` but it won't give any output, while using just `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` does.

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
head -n1 /dev/ttyUSB0 | xcopy
```

replace 1 by the expected number of ouput lines